# My fan is so loud, how do I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, fan

The fan in my computer is just so loud. It seems to be spinning really fast and all the time. Even when I am not using it.

My computer is a 5 year old computer that was just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, this problem did not happen when my computer was running Windows 7.

How is this possible? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question with more info: room temperature? Power supply / GPU / CPU fans are all still running? Which of them is loud? If CPU: what is the average CPU load in Windows task manager? To check which fans are software controlled, please add a [SpeedFan](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) screenshot. Mainboard model and BIOS version?

Comment: When was it last stripped & cleaned?

Comment: @Tetsujin 5 years ago /s

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep on using the computer, please do something about fixing the noisy fan. I always replace a noisy fan for two reasons.

1. I don't like noisy fans.
2. A noisy fan will typically work at half or less than its normal speed, which can cause the computer to overheat and its hardware components to wear out faster.

Computer fans sometimes don't cost much depending on what type of fan needs to be replaced.